# imagecopyresampled Cropping

Tags: php, image, crop

If I have an image 2048 x 2048 and I would like an image 1488x1488 450 pixels down from top and 280 pixels from left

is this the right code  x.png is the 2048 x 2048 picture:

```
<?php

$imagesrc_location = 'x.png';

// Get new sizes
list($srcwidth, $srcheight) = getimagesize($imagesrc_location);

$imagedst = imagecreatetruecolor(1488, 1488);
$imagesrc = imagecreatefrompng($imagesrc_location);

if (imagecopyresampled($imagedst,$imagesrc,0,0,280,450,1488,1488,2048,2048)) { 
    // Output image
    header('Content-type: image/png');
    imagepng($imagedst);
} else {
    echo "Could not resize file";

}
```

Here is a picture showing what I want, the grey part is the cropped picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I think the problem is, your source size will make the `imagecopyresampled` scale it down.  This may work for a crop:

```
imagecopyresampled($imagedst,$imagesrc,0,0,280,450,1488,1488,1488,1488)
```

But look here: http://www.johnconde.net/blog/cropping-an-image-with-php-and-the-gd-library/
I think that what you want is:

```
imagecopy($imagedst,$imagesrc,0,0,280,450,1488,1488)
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopy.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Comment: It is not working for me. I give it this: http://i.min.us/ibvzyAeW9415uv.png and it comes up with this: http://i.min.us/ibyi5KbfTglN2P.png

Comment: Oddly enough `imagecopyresampled($imagedst,$imagesrc,0,0,280,450,1488,1488,1488,1488)` and `imagecopyresampled($imagedst,$imagesrc,0,0,280,450,2048,2048,2048,2048)`  both work. I will never understand this function completely.

Comment: I'm no expert but I think that the two "sizes" you pass at the end of that function only affect scaling.  So if they are the same, then apparently it does no scaling (regardless of actual image sizes).